# Асинхронные сокеты, прием и сортировка данных

Tags: c#, сокеты

Здравствуйте. Возник такой вопрос. Есть асинхронный сервер, с которым соединяются клиенты. Сервер допустим раз в минуту кидает запрос к группе клиентов(клиенты хранятся в списке) с запросом информации. Как мне правильно определить от кого пришли данные по коллбеку приема?

Я вижу это так - сервер отправляет пакет клиенту в формате [ClientID|Command], а клиент в свою очередь возвращает ответ в формате [ClientID|Response]. По приему сервер передает пакет в менеджер, который уже определяет по ClientID кому предназначен пакет и выполняет необходимые функции. В правильном ли направлении я иду, или можно все проще сделать?

Просто если с синхронными сокетами все было просто - отправил данные из функции и получил их в этой-же функции. И не надо думать от кого они. То тут у меня маленько мозг выворачивает. Извините если непонятно объяснил, пишите, я буду пробовать понятнее объяснить. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы не указали язык на котором это делаете. Но обычно внутри обработчика известно из какого конкретно сокета пришли данные. Соответственно сервер просто должен хранить соответствие ClientID и сокета

Comment: Нет, вы делаете совершенно неправильно. Если клиент передает свой ID - он может его подменить, а это дыра в безопасности.

Comment: Язык C#. Я только пошел исправлять данные про ClientID :). Да, данные которые я отправляю с определенного сокета, я на него же и получаю. А вот дальше идея с менеджером правильная? Я просто никак не могу понять механизм сортировки полученных данных в асинхронном варианте.

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с асинхронными сокетами надо использовать асинхронные функции. В таком случае отличия от синхронного варианта будут минимальны. В частности, отправка данных в сокет и их получение обратно будут происходить в одной и той же функции.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, пойду читать про асинхронные функции.